# pandas raises ValueError on DatetimeIndex Conversion

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am converting all ISO-8601 formatted values into Unix Values. For some inexplicable reason this line

```
a_col = pd.DatetimeIndex(a_col).astype(np.int64)/10**6
```

raises the error

> ValueError: Unable to convert 0       2001-06-29
>
> ... (Abbreviated Output of Column
>
> Name: DateCol, dtype: datetime64[ns] to datetime dtype

This is very odd because I've guaranteed that each value is in datetime.datetime format as you can see here:

```
if a_col.dtypes is (np.dtype('object') or np.dtype('O')):
      a_col = a_col.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else epoch)
a_col = pd.DatetimeIndex(a_col).astype(np.int64)/10**6
```

Epoch is datetime.datetime.

When I check the dtypes of the column that gives me an error it's "object), exactly what I'm checking for. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I can't replicate your error: >>> pd.DatetimeIndex(['2001-06-29']).astype(np.int64)/10**6
array([993772800000]). Is there a zero in the date preceding the year? "Unable to convert 0 2001-06-29"

Comment: That's what it looks like. I've posted the dataset here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0yy3ujz5iuybkg/data.xls?dl=0.
To read the csv, I used: data = pd.read_excel(a_file, sheetname=0, skiprows=range(1,2), header=1). The column that's the issue is Job Start Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your time zone is US/Eastern (based on your dataset) and that your DataFrame is named `df`, please try the following:

```
import datetime as dt
from time import mktime
import pytz

df['Job Start Date'] = \
    df['Job Start Date'].apply(lambda x: mktime(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(x)
                                         .astimezone(pytz.UTC).timetuple()))

>>> df['Job Start Date'].head()
0     993816000
1    1080824400
2    1052913600
3    1080824400
4    1075467600
Name: Job Start Date, dtype: float64
```

You first need to make your 'naive' datetime objects timezone aware (to US/Eastern) and then convert them to UTC.  Finally, pass your new UTC aware datetime object as a timetable to the [`mtkime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) function from the time module.

Comment: That does work on the xls from before. However when applied to the same column in another dataset this error arises: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'": https://www.dropbox.com/s/r83el9930ibbhxd/data2.xls?dl=0 
This error didn't occur with the code I was originally using (above). Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: That dataset has one integer value in it (10060130).

Comment: To deal with that, I'm first performing the object np.dtype('object') check, then using your function. It works now. Pretty slow, but I can optimize later. Thanks!!

Comment: I made a separate question out of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830776/replacing-nat-with-epoch-in-pandas It seems like NaT values are not being resolved by these checks. If you have any insight onto this please let me know!