# Replacing NaT with Epoch in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas

NaT missing values are appearing at the end of my dataframe as demonstrated below. This understandably raises the ValueError:

> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 314, in localize
>       loc_dt = tzinfo.normalize(dt.replace(tzinfo=tzinfo))
>   ValueError: month must be in 1..12

I've tried to use both dropna:

```
data[col_name].dropna(0, inplace=True)
```

and fillna, as encouraged by the [Working with Missing Data section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna):

```
data[col_name].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Before either of these lines, I tried to clean the data by replacing non-datetimes with the epoch time:

```
data[col_name] = a_col.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime)  else epoch)
```

Because NaT is technically a datetime this condition wasn't covered by that function. Since [isnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689512/efficiently-checking-if-arbitrary-object-is-nan-in-python-numpy-pandas) will handle this, I wrote this function to apply to data[col_name]:

```
def replace_time(x):
if pd.isnull(x):
    return epoch
elif isinstance(x, datetime.datetime):
    return x
else:
    return epoch
```

Despite the fact that it enters the pd.isnull section, the value isn't changed. However, when I try that function on this series (where the second value is NaT) it works:

```
s = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('20130101'),np.nan,pd.Timestamp('20130102 9:30')],dtype='M8[ns]')
```

Data:

> 2003-04-29 00:00:00
>
> NaT
>
> NaT
>
> NaT

Comment: What version pandas and numpy are you using? Doesn't `dropna` and `fillna` do what you want already?

Comment: Numpy is 1.8.0rc1. Pandas is 0.16.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data[col_name] = a_col.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) 
                                       and not isinstance(x, pd.tslib.NaTType) else epoch)
```

Comment: Can't like this enough.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is you are chain indexing via this expression

```
data[col_name].dropna(0, inplace=True)
```

This potentially modifies a copy and thus nothing will actually change. This is quite tricky to actually have it show a `SettingWithCopy` warning. See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

`.fillna/.dropna` ARE the appropriate ways to fill `datetime64[ns]` dtypes. Using an `.apply` is quite inefficient.

```
In [16]: df = DataFrame({ 'date' : pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('20130101'),np.nan,pd.Timestamp('20130102 9:30')]) })

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                 date
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1                 NaT
2 2013-01-02 09:30:00

In [18]: df.date.fillna(0)
Out[18]: 
0   2013-01-01 00:00:00
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00
2   2013-01-02 09:30:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: this is a much more efficient method and should be the accepted answer